# Mysql erro 1215: Não é possível adicionar restrição de chave estrangeira

Tags: sql, mysql

---

- ***Como resolvo este erro ? Sei que um dos motivos para isso acontecer é
  que as colunas precisam ter o mesmo tamanho e a mesma especificação.
  Mas já tentei de tudo e não está funcionando.***

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE DATABASE`sistema`/*!40100DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8*/;
use sistema;
drop database sistema;

CREATE TABLE`conta`(
    `numero`int(9)NOT NULL,
    `agencia`int(4)NOT NULL,
    `saldo`float NOT NULL,
    `limite`float NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`numero`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE`correntista`(
    `cpf`varchar(11)NOT NULL,
    `nome`varchar(60)NOT NULL,
    `datanascimento`date NOT NULL,
    `sexo`varchar(1)NOT NULL,
    `idendereco`int(9)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `numero`int(9)NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`cpf`),
    KEY`idendereco`(`idendereco`),
    KEY`numero`(`numero`),
    CONSTRAINT`correntista_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY(`idendereco`)
        REFERENCES`endereco` (`idendereco`),
    CONSTRAINT`correntista_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY(`numero`)
        REFERENCES`conta`(`numero`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE`endereco`(
    `idendereco`int(9)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cep`varchar(8)NOT NULL,
    `logradouro`varchar(60)NOT NULL,
    `tipo`varchar(40)NOT NULL,
    `numero`int(9)NOT NULL,
    `bairro`varchar(40)NOT NULL,
    `cidade`varchar(60)NOT NULL,
    `uf`varchar(2)NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`idendereco`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duas coisas:

1 - Você está a tentar criar uma *FOREIGN KEY* referenciando uma tabela que ainda não existe.
A criação da tabela `correntista` tem de ser feita após a criação das outras duas.

2 - Inclua um espaço entre *REFERENCES* e o nome da tabela.

Experimente [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c75d2)

**<sub>Nota:</sub>** <sub>Retire também o *AUTO_INCREMENT* do campo `idendereco` da tabela `correntista`</sub>

Comment: Muito obrigado, o problema estava no espaçamento entre o REFERENCES e o nome da tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Crie primeiro as tabelas sem as FK
No final faz um ALTER TABLE

Exemplo:
ALTER TABLE `pers_addresses`
ADD CONSTRAINT `correntista_ibfk_11` FOREIGN KEY (`idendereco`) REFERENCES `endereco` (`idendereco`)

Answer (score -2):

Crie as tabelas na ordem certa.
Exemplor: "CREATE TABLE `conta`", "CREATE TABLE `endereco`" e "CREATE TABLE `correntista`".

O erro também pode ser ocasionado pelo motivo de uma key de referencia que não é única...
Exemplo:

```
[..]
REFERENCES `tabela` (`coluna`)
[..]
```

O conteúdo da coluna tem que ser única.

Exemplo:

```
[...]
  `coluna` int(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
[...]
```

As FOREIGN tem que manter os espaços.

Além de ter o mesmo tamanho.